# Common Parse error: "in" in a function that call other functions OCaml

Tags: list, function, multidimensional-array, ocaml

Well this `Parse error: "in" expected after [binding] (in [expr])`
 is a common error as far I have searched in `Ocaml` users, but in the examples I saw I didnt found the answer for my error, then I will explain my problem:

I declared this function:

```
let rec unit_propag xs  =

    let cuAux = teste xs 
    let updatelist = funfilter (List.hd(List.hd cuAux)) (xs) 
    let updatelist2 = filtraelem (negar(List.hd(List.hd cuAux))) (updatelist)

if(not(List.mem [] xs) && (teste xs <> []))
then 
    unit_propag updatelist2
;;
```

The functions I am using inside this code were declared before like this:

```
 let funfilter elem xs = List.filter (fun inner -> not (List.mem elem inner)) xs;;

let filtraele elem l = List.map( fun y -> List.filter (fun x -> x <> elem) y)l;;

let teste xs = List.filter(fun inner ->(is_single inner)inner)xs;;

let is_single xs = function
|[_]    -> true
|_  -> false
;;
let negar l =
match l with
V x -> N x
|N x    -> V x
|B  -> T
|T  -> B
;;
```

But not by this order.
Well they were all doing what I wanted to do, but now when I declared `unit_propag` and tried to compile, I had an error in line of

```
let cuAux = teste xs
```

It said:

```
File "exc.ml", line 251, characters 20-22:
Parse error: "in" expected after [binding] (in [expr])
Error while running external preprocessor
Command line: camlp4o 'exc.ml' > /tmp/ocamlpp5a7c3d
```

Then I tried to add a `;` on the end of each function, and then my ***"in"*** error appeared on the line of the last function, is this case `unit_propag updatelist2`

What I am doing wrong? people usually say that this kind of errors occurs before that code, but when i comment this function the program compiles perfectly.

I need to post more of my code? Or i need to be more clear in my question?
Is that possible to do in `Ocaml` or I am doing something that I cant?

Thanks

Comment: Using a proper auto indentation tool like ocaml-mode, tuareg-mode or ocp-indent can easily avoid this sort of problem.  If the auto-indentation result is different what you think it is likely that you made a syntax error somewhere near there.

Comment: I am now using auto indentation programs thnx for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says you're missing `in`, so it seems strange to solve it by adding `;` :-)

Anyway, you're missing the keyword `in` after all the `let` keywords in your function `unit_propag`.

You should write it like this:

```
let rec unit_propag xs  =
    let cuAux = teste xs in
    let updatelist = funfilter (List.hd(List.hd cuAux)) (xs) in
    let updatelist2 =
        filtraelem (negar(List.hd(List.hd cuAux))) (updatelist)
    in
    if (not (List.mem [] xs) && (teste xs <> [])) then 
       unit_propag updatelist2
```

The basic issue has been explained many times here (as you note). Basically there are two uses of the keyword `let`. At the outer level it defines the values in a module. Inside another definition it defines a local variable and *must* be followed by `in`. These three `let`s are inside the definition of `unit_propag`.

Another attempt to explain the use of `let` is here: [OCaml: Call function within another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414762/ocaml-call-function-within-another-function/36414796#36414796).

Comment: Cant believe I didn't tested it! Thanks now I understand better this kind of situations